Coveo number field being indexed as decimal instead of integer
In Sitecore I have a custom computed field that needs to be an integer in Cove, but instead is being processed as a decimal. I am not sure what I have wrong in the configuration
public class YearFacetComputedField : IComputedIndexField
{
    public string FieldName { get; set; }

    public string ReturnType { get { return "Number"; } set { } }

    public object ComputeFieldValue(IIndexable indexable)
    {
        // Returning null means that the field won't be created.
        // By default, any returned value is automatically converted into a string.
        try
        {
            var service = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(INewsDateService)) as INewsDateService;
            var newsDate = service?.GetNewsDate(item) ?? DateTime.MinValue;
            if(newsDate == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                return null;
            }
            return newsDate.Year;
        }
        catch
        {
            Log.SingleError($"Error occurred in {this.GetType().FullName}", this);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

in the fieldMap:
<fieldType fieldName="searchnewsyear" isFacet="true" settingType="Coveo.Framework.Configuration.FieldConfiguration, Coveo.Framework" returnType="System.Integer "/>

I tried changing the returnType in the fieldMap to System.Int32 and I tried changing the ReturnType in the computed field to "Integer" and "Int32" but my changes have caused it to either stay a decimal in Coveo or become a string. What's the correct configuration for it to be an integer in Coveo?


Figured it out. ReturnType "Number" sets it to a decimal in Coveo, "Integer" will set it correctly. The documentation for the return types is here
